# How do I group by a Nested property's Nested property (part II)

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

In a previous post (http://bit.ly/bbIthV) i asked how to Group a list of Persons by their nested Address.State, when Address might be null.

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) gave a perfect answer to my question:

`//Create a dummy replacement for when a person has no addresses
Address dummyAddress = new Address { State = "" };
people.GroupBy(p => (p.Addresses.GetFirstOrDefault() ?? dummyAddress).State);`

But seeing the results, I see that I wasn't asking the right quesion.

If I have 6 people, each one living at n addresses, the above will only get 6 groups...whereas I should instead be getting a group of persons, grouped by the key State that could be found by:

`var distinctAddresses = people.SelectMany(p=>p.Addresses).City).Distint();`

I think the answer will involve a GroupJoin of some kind, but I haven't gotten very far...

`//Back where I started:
var y = addresses.GroupJoin(persons,a => a.State, p => p.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(),
 (a,p)=> p);
//Doesn't compile...
var y = addresses.GroupJoin(persons,a => a, p => p.Addresses, (a,p)=> p);`

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to proceed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm slightly confused. It would be great if you could provide sample input, output.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler using query syntax:

```
var q = from p in People
        group p by p.Address.State into g
        select g;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var q =
    (from p in people
     from a in p.Addresses
     group p by a.State ?? "")
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Distinct())
```